# Find active TCP servers on a network without looping through IPs

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, server, client

From my TCP client, how can I find all the active TCP servers listening on a particular port, without needing to loop through all the IP addresses in the network? Or is there a faster way to loop through all the IP addresses?

Comment: You cant.  Unless a specific application has a broadcast/response system such as SQL

Comment: You may want to look up "[service discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_discovery)"

Comment: TCP doesn't have clients or servers; TCP creates peer connections. The client/server concept is an application concept.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

You can listen for broadcasts (e.g. ARP) to find out which IP addresses are actually used and if there are any services advertising themselves, but this is not reliable and there is no standard, catch-all way.

You can't even query a given host which services have listening ports open because there's no general service for that.